# line spacing in the 'amsart' document class

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, amsart

In the 'amsart' document class, the 'setspace' package doesn't work.  The 'linespread' command, in the preamble, does work, but I don't want the same line spacing throughout my document (i.e. I want certain sections to be single-spaced, some others to be double-spaced, etc.).  How can I do this?

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have problems with `setspace` and `amsart`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \singlespacing
  \kant[1]
  \onehalfspacing
  \kant[2]
  \begin{spacing}{2.5}
    \kant[3]
  \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why is it that when I use the environment \begin{doublespace}...\end{doublespace}, it double-spaces the whole page, and not just the portion of the page I want double-spaced?

Comment: @Rohan I can't reproduce it. May be you need to update or something.